# How do I create a cronjob for these commands?

Tags: python, bash, cron, virtualenv, cron-task

I want to a up a cron job to run a python script each day within a virtual environment. So I've tried to set up a cron job but it does not seem to execute.

If I were to run the program from terminal normally, I would type:

1. `source ig/venv/bin/activat` enter to activate my virtual environment
2. `cd ig/mybot/src/` navigate to my directory
3. `python ultimate.py` run my program

SO FAR this is my cron job. I've set it to 1 to run every minute just so I can see that it is working but nothing happens.

```
1   *   *   *   *   source ig/venv/bin/activate && cd ig/mybot/src/ && python ultimate.py
```

*Edit: I have updated my program so no command line prompts are required. I am just needing to run these three simple commands.*

Comment: just put your commands inside the file..but I don't think `cron` can enter `1` for you --> https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/345985/216076

Comment: "...my python script prompts me..." cron jobs cannot be interactive.

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap this up with another python script itself. Create a new python script and run it instead of cron.

Have a look into [subprocess](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html) module.

Example:
Your command would become `subprocess.call(['source','ig/venv/bin/activate'])`
inside the wrapper python script.

Also, `input("Enter the value")` will prompt you for user input.

With the above two, your problem will be solved pythonically.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if it's a good idea, but you could do a script like this.

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

PYTHON_PROJECT_DIR=/path/to/python/project/dir

pushd ${PYTHON_PROJECT_DIR}

VALUES="first line of stream\nsecondline of stream\n"

pipenv run /path/to/your/script.py < (echo -e $VALUES)

popd
```

`pushd` and `popd` are commands to move with the directory stack, so you'll be in the directory in the top of the stack, so by adding one directory, you *move* to the working directory, and by poping you'll get back to the initial position.

Using `pipenv` allows you to run the scripts in the virtual enviroment (It's not that hard to configure), that way you'll use the enviroment variables in the `.env` files for the project, and you'll only use the dependencies of this project. (python related).

If you pass the values like this, the python script when ever it requests a value from `stdin` it will use the values that you echoed (line by line, first line is first input and so on)

This could be a way.

Personally when ever I do `cronjobs` I like to run directly bash scripts, because, I could add extra logging, so having the wrapper script doesn't seem that unreasonable.

Another thing you could do, Is to get the python executable path (for the virtual enviroment), and use that as interpreter, by replacing the `#!/usr/bin/env python` to `#!/path/to/pythons/virtual/env/interpreter`
but you won't get the `.env variables` (may be there is a way to actually get them.